# Best OOP design for database

Tags: c++, oop

For a school assignment I have to create a C++ program that will create and manage a binary flat file database containing students and undergrad students. The undergrad students are basically the same as normal students, but with some added fields. A given hint is that we could use templates.

My problem is in structuring this design. I've tried the following:

- Creating a `Person` class containing `string` variables with a `student` and an `undergrad` class that inherit from it and add more variables for fields. This works but it becomes very hard to add more types of people later on, so I tried:
- Creating a `Person` class that contains a `map<string, string>` from which `Undergrad` and `Student` inherit, and a `database` class containing a `vector<Person>` to which those are added. In the `Person::map<string, string>` I added the different fields and their values, like name, address etc.

I'm not sure if I'm going the right way with this. Is there a standard design pattern that's used for things like this?

Comment: Close voter, what were you thinking?

Comment: @Golez - Come on, "What is the best design for a database?".

Comment: @BoPersson I know this isn't a question with a single, obvious answer, but I think I can learn much more from this assignment if I ask input from the community, instead of just finishing the course with the first solution that works. In retrospect, I could have chosen a better title though, yes.

Comment: @Sietse - StackOverflow just doesn't like questions that cannot be  answered. It fits badly with the Q&A concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach depends more on what you need the system to do. Your first approach is more standard c++ architecture if you know the system will be specialized around the requirements you've listed and you want better runtime performance.

The map way would allow you to implement a more generalized approach, but at a cost of clarity, specialized accessors, and more so I'm guessing it is *not* the approach your teacher is seeking.

If you know all the requirements of the system ( what kind of queries will be made, what is it expected to support, etc ) it will better inform your decision, so you should get clarity on that for sure.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Beware of class hierarchies for "inheritance". Most of the time you will only derive if there is a "Liskov Substitution Principle", i.e. that you can take an object called "person" and call a function on that without knowing what their real type is.

Note that Liskov was a woman and published this principle in the early 80s I think.